# How to display GeoJson object on bing map?

Tags: maps, geojson, bing-maps

I am trying to call an api with location to display a GeoJson object on the bing map. I wrote the code below but nothing gets displayed on the map and no errors also.

Could you please see anything wrong with this code?

```
var api = 'https://api/locations';

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {

        Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl(api,
            function (shapes) {
                //Add the shape(s) to the map.
                map.entities.push(shapes);
            }, 'callback');
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does the service you are calling wrap the response with JavaScript? Your code has 'callback' which is telling Bing Maps to make a JSONP request which will append `&callback=[some internal callback function]` to the request. If your service doesn't use JSONP and is hosted on the same domain or is on a CORs enabled endpoint, remove the `callback` parameter from your code.

Comment: yes, the service is GeoJson api and it is not hosted in the same domain.

Comment: browser developer tools shows warning: "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response" and shows error:   "mapcontrol?callback=GetMap:11 Uncaught Error: Network error occured while getting geoJson data from https://...."

Comment: If the service has an option to wrap the response in a function call, you can try loading the data using a script tag like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsV8CodeSamples/blob/master/Samples/GeoJSON/GeoJson_CrossDomain_NoJsonp.html If that doesn't work, you likely will need a proxy service to grab the data server side and pass it down to your app on your domain.